# Expandablelist view not scroll in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have created one main fragment.It contains the appbar layout and nestedscrollview.Dynamic fragments is created inside the nested scrollview. Appbar layout is scrolling fine but inside all fragments i have implemented the expandablelistview not scroll.The expandable list contain child also not scroll inside the fragments.please anyone help me to fix this issue.

Mainactivity layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/editprofilelayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/materialup_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                >​
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/restaurantimage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/noodles"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Casa Dolce"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            >
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragmentParent"

                android:name="abservetech.com.foodapp.FragmentParent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAddPage"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Expandablelistview xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/dullwhite">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show vegetarian dishes"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
    </ExpandableListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

`